# Is it true that if $cl(S) = int(S) \cup \partial (S)$ and $cl(S) = S \cup \partial (S)$ then $int(S) = S$ which means $S$ is open?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Like the title says, I know:

$cl(S) = int(S) \cup \partial (S)$

But also;

$cl(S) = S \cup \partial (S)$

But then $S = int(S)$ which is only true if $S$ is an open set. Where is this limitation found in the above two equations? Of course not all sets are open. Is it true $cl(S) = S \cup \partial (S)$ holds only if $S$ is open?

Comment: It seems that if $S$ is closed, both conditions are also satisfied.  The problem in your reasoning is that you can't subtract sets like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements are true, but the union is not disjoint, i.e. what you have does not imply $int(S)=S$ - by taking out the boundary, you might take out stuff from $S$.

Comment: I do not completely understand it yet, so both statements are true but it does not imply $int(S) = S$. But surely if I then say $cl(S) \setminus cl(S) = \emptyset$, thus $(int(S) \cup \partial S) \setminus (S \cup \partial S) = \emptyset$, meaning $int(S) \setminus S = \emptyset$, hence $int(S) = S$?

Comment: Bot statements for example imply that $S-\partial S=int(S)$, which is true.

Comment: Can you explain how you find that from the two statements?

Comment: $int(S)\cup\partial S= S \cup \partial S$, take out $\partial S$ on both sides and use that $\partial S$ and $int S$ are disjoint.

Comment: Considering what you wrote up there- $int(S)-S=\emptyset$ implies that $int(S)\subset S$, but not the other direction.

Comment: I get it, you could say $cl(S) = S \cup \partial S$ is a more generalized version of $cl(S) = int(S) \cup \partial S$, right? Thanks ;)

Comment: If you mean "bigger" by "more generalized", then yes.

Answer (score 0):

NO.... Counterexample: In the space $\mathbb R,$ let $S=\mathbb Q.$ We have    $$\partial (S)=\bar S\cup  \overline {\mathbb R\backslash S}=\overline { \mathbb Q }\cap \overline {\mathbb {R \backslash  Q}}=  \overline {\mathbb Q}=\bar S=\mathbb R.$$ Therefore ,$\mathbb R= \bar S=$ int $(S)\cup \partial (S)=S\cup \mathbb \partial (S)$ but int $(S)=\phi \ne S.$

Your error is in assuming that int$(S)\cup \partial (S)=S\cup \partial (S)\implies$  int $(S)=S.$ In general $A\cup B= C\cup B$ does not imply $A=C.$
We have $A\cup B=C\cup B \iff A$ \ $B$=$C$ \ $B.$